# Web Scraping with two system security

Tags: python, html, authentication, web-scraping

good, i am going to tell you this. I don't understand how to do for access to a site of website with two system security. i explain me, the first security system is most common because is only username and password, i manage to do that. but the second security system is only password (different that first system) then i don't know how to pass the second system because i used a requerest.session() the once in the username and password. i want stand out that the first security system is in other url different that the second security system.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


datos = {
'username':'USERNAME',
'password':'PASSWORD'
}

security_key = {
'password':'PASSWORD'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    login_url = 'https://www.cuprum.cl/wwwcuprum/Login.aspx'  #than is a first security(login)
    page = s.post(login_url, data=datos)

    segurity_key_url = 'https://www.cuprum.cl/wwwCuprum/wwwClaves/ClaveSeguridad/valida_cs_Previred.aspx?op=DF&id=8' #than is a second security(only password)
    segurity = s.post(segurity_key_url, data=segurity_key, headers=dict(referer=segurity_key_url))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(segurity.content, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())

    cambio_url = 'https://www.cuprum.cl/wwwCuprum/wwwFondos/Cambio/cambio_fondo.aspx?target=Contenido&id=8'
    cambios = s.get(cambio_url)
    print(cambios.content)
```

so this is what i have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have successfully authenticated the first level. But when i check the website, the passing data parameters are different
[image: See the below image for reference]

Since its an ASP website. You can check this link [Visit Link](https://medium.com/@simranpandey97/web-scraper-for-aspx-form-based-webpages-b8828085e4a2)

Hope this might helps you